# Google Cloud Kubernetes Laravel Get Visitor IP

Tags: laravel, nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ip

I'm trying to get visitor IP on my Laravel application that uses Nginx on Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine, under load balancer.

I have set up TrustProxies.php like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $proxies = '*';

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

I have also tried

```
protected $proxies = '**';
```

And

```
protected $proxies = ['loadbalancer_ip_here'];
```

No matter what I have tried, it will always return load balancer ip.

Might this be caused by Nginx configuration? Help appreciated.

Comment: What is you Ingress class? Is it the nginx you are talking about or is the nginx you web server bundled in your container?

Comment: @MathieuBour Nginx is bundled in container, there is only 1 application running, so there is no Ingress classes used.

Comment: Well, I suggest you to add you vhost in the question, so everyone can check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set traffic policy in your nginx service

```
externalTrafficPolicy: "Local"
```

and also

```
healthCheckNodePort: "numeric port number for the service"
```

More details in [Preserving the client source IP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip) doc